# Practical application of the Hoeffding inequality

Tags: machine-learning

I found this [unanswered question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1313021/152225) in SE-Mathematics from 2015... too old to be migrated to CV. So I'm asking the same question here, and you can upvote the OP in the sister community.

If you draw a proportion of red marbles $k\leq 0.1$ in a sample of $N=10$ from a giant urn containing a proportion of red marbles of $\mu=0.9$, the probability of obtaining a difference of such magnitude or more: $\mathbb P(\text{no.red})\leq 1$ can be calculated using the binomial distribution, and corresponds to `pbinom(q = 1, size = 10, prob = .9)    [1] 9.1e-09`.

How can you reconcile this negligible value with the information afforded by the Hoeffding Inequality?

$P(|k - \mu| > \epsilon) \leq 2e^{-2\epsilon^2 N}$.

Plugging in the difference observed (up to $0.9$) we end up with:

$P(0.9\geq\epsilon)\leq 2e^{-2\epsilon^2 10}$

I would assume that if $\epsilon$ denotes the "tolerance for error", we should be able to set a very low $\epsilon$, but the actual observed proportion is not in the RHS of the inequality, and $N$ is not big enough to set a very low tolerance value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood. Actually you set $\varepsilon = |0.9-0.2| = 0.7$ and $N=10$ in the inequality and then simply compute. The $0.7$ comes from
$$P(k \le 0.1) = P(k < 0.2) = P(|k - \mu| > 0.7)$$
Hence,
$$P(|k-\mu| > 0.7) \le 2e^{-2\cdot 0.7^2\cdot 10} = 2 e^{-9.8} \approx 10^{-4}$$
NB that this is not a very good bound.

Comment: Thank you. How does the bound relate to the binomial calculation?

Comment: What do you mean? The accurate probability satisfies the inequality with a lot of room, $9.1\cdot 10^{-9} \approx 10^{-8} << 10^{-4}$.